# Prove the size of the result of a cartesian product is equal to the product of the size of the two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We want to show:

$$|S_1 \times S_2| = |S_1| \cdot |S_2|$$

I am not sure how to go about showing this in general terms. I believe that we will need to use the definition of the cartesian product during this, so that is where I am at right now.

$$S_1 \times S_2 = \{(a,b): a \in S_1 \; \text{and} \; b \in S_2\}$$

These are finite sets.

Comment: what are the cardinalities of of $S_1$ and $S_2$? finite? countable? uncountable?

Comment: That is the *definition* of cardinal multiplication. So it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: If by |S| you mean the cardinal of S, then |SxT| is the definition of  |S|.|T|.

Comment: Sorry for leaving out the details, yes these are using finite sets.

Answer (score 4):

Say $S_1 = \{a,b\}$ and $S_2=\{x,y,z\}$.  Then

$$
S_1\times S_2= \big\{ (a,x),\ (a,y),\ (a,z),\ (b,x),\ (b,y),\ (b,z) \big\}.
$$
So you can look at it in either of two ways:
$$
\big\{ \underbrace{(a,x),\ (a,y),\ (a,z)},\ \underbrace{(b,x),\ (b,y),\ (b,z)} \big\}.
$$
$$
\big\{ \underbrace{(a,x),\ (b,x)},\ \underbrace{(a,y),\ (b,y)},\ \underbrace{(a,z),\ (b,z)} \big\}
$$
The first is a sum of two $3$s; the second is a sum of three $2$s.  So the first is $2\times3$ and the second is $3\times 2$.  That's one way of knowing that $2\times3$ is the same number as $3\times2$.

$$
|S_1|\times|S_2| = \sum_{a\in S_1}\ \sum_{x\in S_2}\ 1 = \sum_{(a,x)\in S_1\times S_2} \  1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response @Michael Hardy. I understand and am able to demonstrate the relationship by creating my own sets and going through the calculations as you did, what I struggle with is demonstrating it in general terms.

Comment: I think the most important concept here is fixing one variable while the other iterates

Answer (score 1):

If $|S_1| = m$ and $S_2 =n$, you could show this by [creating a bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection#Bijections_and_cardinality),

$$\phi : S_1 \times S_2 \mapsto \{1, 2, \ldots, mn \} $$

If you're familiar with the concept of [row/column - major ordering for storing matrices as a flat array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), there is a natural mapping to use. Denote the elements of $S_1$ as $a_1, \ldots, a_m$, and elements of $S_2$ as $b_1, \ldots, b_n$. Then imagining the pairs of elements in an $m \times n$ matrix, use the column-major mapping:

$$\phi(a_i,b_j) = n(i-1) + j$$

You'll have to fool around with some modular arithmetic to give the inverse.

Comment: I appreciate your input @Chester. I am thinking that this may be a little too advanced for what I'm trying to show though, as we haven't learned any of what you mentioned.

Comment: In plain english, we're showing the size of the set, $|S_1 \times S_2|$ by coming up with a correspondence between this set and the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, mn\}$. If we're successful, then the two must be the same size.... If you have a bag of marbles and a bag of skittles, you could show they each contain the same number by lining them up one-by-one next to each other, basically.